# Circuitikz logic port design

Tags: circuitikz

Is there some reason why the `center` anchor for circuitikz logic gates are so far from the actual center (`\pgfpointorigin`)?  Is this just where the author liked to align his gates and was too lazy to add a new anchor and use `[anchor=anchorname]`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw[red] (-1,0) -- (1,0) (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\node[american or port] (A) at (0,0) {};
\draw[green] (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Probably `pgfcirctripoles.tex` line 182. I find no reason.

Comment: My best guess is that it is pointless to refer to the actual center of a port. Therefore the anchor is set to somewhere that **looks** like a wise choice.

Comment: Whether this is a bug of a feature, we will probably have to preserve backward compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @JohnKormylo, whether it's a bug or feature, it is preserved for backward compatibility. But `center` anchor can be set at actual center with the command

```
% From Circuitikz version 0.9.0
\ctikzset{logic ports origin=center}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{logic ports origin=center}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw[red] (-1,0) -- (1,0) (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\node[american or port] (A) at (0,0) {};
\draw[green] (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```