# Changing Default Label Text in Custom Shape During Instantiation

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I have created my custom electric component named `myIC` using the `circuitikz.sty` library. `myIC` has three pins labeled `PinA`, `PinB`, `PinC` and a default label `myIClabel`. I defined this component within the `pgfdeclareshape` environment, allowing me to easily incorporate it into a `circuitikz` environment.

**Question**: How can I change the default label text `myIClabel` during the instantiation of `myIC`? See the output screenshot below

**CODE**:

```
\documentclass[border=0cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\pgfdeclareshape{myIC}{
    
    % define saved anchor
    % ----------------------------------------
      \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
      
    % define Connectors relative to the center
    % ----------------------------------------
      % Pin A:
      \savedanchor\myICpinA{\pgfpoint{-30}{10}}
      \anchor{PinA}{\myICpinA}
      % Pin B:
      \savedanchor\myICpinB{\pgfpoint{-30}{-10}}
      \anchor{PinB}{\myICpinB}
      % Pin C:
      \savedanchor\myICpinC{\pgfpoint{30}{0}}
      \anchor{PinC}{\myICpinC}
        
    \foregroundpath{
        
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-30}{-30}}{\pgfpoint{30}{30}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        
        \pgftext[left,  at={\myICpinA}]{PinA}
        \pgftext[left,  at={\myICpinB}]{PinB}
        \pgftext[right, at={\myICpinC}]{PinC}
        
        % my static label
        \pgftext[center, at={\pgfpoint{0}{35}}]{\small\textcolor{black}{myIClabel}}
        
        }
    
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        % Instance of the custom component in red
        \draw (0,0) node[myIC, red] (myIC1) {};
        % Another instance in green
        \draw (3,0) node[myIC, green] (myIC2) {};
        % Yet another instance in blue
        \draw (6,0) node[myIC, blue] (myIC3) {};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image]

Comment: Hi Marco, what do you mean with "assigning labels"? To name a node you just do something like `node [myIC](labelA){}`. And again, this has no relation with `circuitikz`. Question: why don't you use a distributed `circuitikz` instead of the git version? And why not using `circuititz` provided chip or muxdemux  components?

Comment: Or do you want to add text at the top of the box? In that case, you need to define a `text` anchor  and then say ` node[myIC]{a label}`

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372993/is-it-possible-to-implement-multiple-input-logic-ports-with-circuitikz/372996?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C33.7654#372996 which uses `\anchor{text}{\pgfpoint{-.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox}{\dimexpr.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox-.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox}}`

Comment: @Rmano, thank you once more for your comment. When I create an instance of the `myIC` component inside the `circuitikz` environment, I want to label this node. For instance, I'd like to do this: `\draw (0,0) node[myIC, red, myLabel=testLabel1] {};`. Feel free to provide some code using only `circuitikz` instead using the git version :)? Best regards

Comment: @Rmano: Just a quick update, I've switched from the `circuitikzgit` package to the `circuitikz` package since it gives me the same result. I edited my question. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @Rmano: Note that I clarified my question because I believe it was not well-written. Now, the question should be clearly defined.

Comment: Do you just want the label to be typeset or do you want to refer to the shape later by name? I'm assuming the former, but then you mention wanting to name the node. But this can't you do that already?

Comment: @cfr: thanks for your support. The current situation is that when I create an instance of `myIC`, the default label `myIClabel` appears. So far, so good. However, some instances should have a different label other than `myIClabel`.

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer I posted an answer which does what you want, as I understand it. If that's not it, I don't understand the question. I addressed both interpretations which seemed plausible, but focused on the labelling rather than naming. So ...

Comment: @cfr: I saw your answer, and it's exactly what I was looking for. The only thing is that there is no default value anymore, correct?

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer `.initial` sets the default. Try it.

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer Or see edit.

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer I added (for the next version) features to `muxdemux` that should address all your needs. I have been thinking about it for a long time, but your question prompted me to tackle it... so thanks!  https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/746

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking about labelling or naming, as you use both terms somewhere in your question/comments, and these are rather different things.

If you want the label's content to be configurable, you can just define a key using `pgfkeys` and use the value in place of the fixed text.

[image: shapes with customised labels]

[image: shapes with customised and default labels]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}

\pgfdeclareshape{myIC}{
  % define saved anchor
  \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
  % Pins
  \savedanchor\myICpinA{\pgfpoint{-30}{10}}
  \anchor{PinA}{\myICpinA}
  \savedanchor\myICpinB{\pgfpoint{-30}{-10}}
  \anchor{PinB}{\myICpinB}
  \savedanchor\myICpinC{\pgfpoint{30}{0}}
  \anchor{PinC}{\myICpinC}
  \foregroundpath{
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-30}{-30}}{\pgfpoint{30}{30}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
    \pgftext[left,  at={\myICpinA}]{PinA}
    \pgftext[left,  at={\myICpinB}]{PinB}
    \pgftext[right, at={\myICpinC}]{PinC}
    % my static label
    \pgftext[center, at={\pgfpoint{0}{35}}]{\small\textcolor{black}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/mm/myLabel}}}
  }
}
\pgfqkeys{/mm}{myLabel/.initial=myIClabel}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  % Instance of the custom component in red
  \draw (0,0) node[myIC, red, /mm/myLabel=coch] (myIC1) {};
  % Another instance in green
  \draw (3,0) node[myIC, green, /mm/myLabel=gwyrdd] (myIC2) {};
  % Yet another instance in blue
  \draw (6,0) node[myIC, blue, /mm/myLabel=glas] (myIC3) {};
\end{circuitikz}
\begin{circuitikz}
  % Instance of the custom component in red
  \draw (0,0) node[myIC, red, /mm/myLabel=coch] (myIC1) {};
  % Another instance in green
  \draw (3,0) node[myIC, green, /mm/myLabel=gwyrdd] (myIC2) {};
  % Yet another instance in blue
  \draw (6,0) node[myIC, blue, /mm/myLabel=glas] (myIC3) {};
  \draw (myIC1.PinC) -|- (myIC2.PinA);
  \draw (9,0) node[myIC, magenta] (myIC4) {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

If you want the ability to name the nodes in the PGF/Ti*k*Z sense, you already have that and are already using it. However, your shape obviously has non-standard anchors, so you can use the nodes later, but only with the anchors they actually have.

Comment: thanks for your reply: what means `/mm/myLabel`? Is that a path? Best regards

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer Yes. It's good practice to use a distinct path for custom keys. If you use `/pgf/myLabel` or `/tikz/myLabel` the chances of conflicts are obviously much higher.

Comment: ah ok :) mm stands for Marco Moldenhauer. thanks a lot

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer Oh, yes. Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Your whole user name was too much typing ;).

Comment: by the way what is the difference 'naming' or 'labeling' a node?

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer The names of the nodes in my example are `myIC1`, `myIC2`, `myIC3` etc. The labels are separate nodes with text content `coch`, `gwyrdd` etc. The name isn't (typically) typeset. It just lets you refer to the node e.g. when you join their pins, you're using their names. The label is nothing really to do with the main node. It's just a convenience to define it at the same time, but it's a separate node. The label doesn't have a name (at least, not generally).

Comment: @cfr shouldn't the anchors like `\anchor{PinA}{\myICpinaA}` ... etc. ? As it is, it does not compile for me...

Comment: @Rmano Yes, it should. I copy-pasted the second picture from my other answer about this and forgot that part of the definition had changed, too. Thanks.